# Who was the mother of Avraham's daughter?

Tags: historical-figures, family-members, vayera, abraham, bava-batra

According to one opinion in the Gemarah ([Bava Basra 16b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=16b&format=pdf), also [141a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=141&format=pdf)), when it says Avraham was blessed with everything ([Bereishit 24:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8219#v=1)) it means that he had a daughter. **Who was her mother?**

Answer (score 14):

Tosfos in [Bava Basra 141a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=141&format=pdf) writes:

> בת היה לו ובכל שמה. וא"ת ולמה לא השיאה ליצחק למ"ד בפרק ארבע מיתות
>   (סנהדרין דף נח:) דבן נח מותר באחותו וי"ל דשמא קטנה היתה ולא רצה עדיין
>   להשיאה ליצחק אי נמי מהגר היתה לו ולא משרה ולכך לא רצה להשיאה ליצחק

Tosfos asks, if Avraham Avinu had a daughter why didn't Yitzchak marry her, according to the opinion that a *ben noach* (lit. "descendant of Noah;" any non-Jew) is allowed to marry a sister, why didn't Avraham have Yitzchak marry her? Tosfos answers that maybe she was too young to get married; another answer Tosfos gives is that this daughter was from Hagar, and Avraham didn't want to marry Yitzchak to her.

So from Tosfos' answers she could have been from **Sarah** (first answer of Tosfos) or **Hagar** (second asnwer of Tosfos).

Comment: Well, Sarah and Hagar *are* the only two options...

Comment: @Doniel, Keturah also...if you assume Keturah and Hagar are different people

Comment: She couldn't have been less than three. So she was possibly older than Rivka. Unless Tosafos is rejecting that opinion.....

Comment: Indeed,it seems like Tosfos in Yevamos 61b takes the stance that Rivka was 14 years of age when she got married. Even though he brings diff opinions, it seems like he likes Rav Shmuel Chasids opinion.